# Faltering report with pandas profiling after converting numeric values to categorical values

Tags: python, pandas, report, profiling, pandas-profiling

I'm currently working with pandas profiling and I have a problem with creating a proper report. Because when I just read the csv file, the columns are in the wrong data type. Instead of categorical, the values were labeled as numeric values. When I now try to define the specific datatype within the read_csv method, the creation of the report stucks at a certain point and takes forever (I canceled it after 30 mins). When I dont change the datatype of the values, the report is done in less then a minute.

Here are also the output of df_data.isnull().sum():

```
A                   0
B                   0
C                   3
D                   0
E                   0
F                   0
G               86317
H                  39
I                6871
J                   0
```

I tried to cast the datatypes within the read_csv:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=['A', 'B'], dtype={
    'C' : 'string',
    'D' : 'string',
    'E' : 'string'
}
)
```

And I've also tried to cast the datatypes with dtypes() after a normal read_csv:

```
df_data = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
df_data['C'] = df_data['A'].astype(str)
df_data['D'] = df_data['A'].astype(str)
df_data['E'] = df_data['A'].astype(str)
```

Both ways had the same result: a report that stucks halfway through

Comment: This strikes me as a problem with the input data rather than a pandas problem. Is it possible for you to share the data or at least create an example of the input data that has the same issues, so that we can reproduce this?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'll create a example input for you

Answer (score 0):

I converted the data in the type_schema, like this:

df_data = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
type_schema = {
'A' : 'datetime',
'B' : 'categorical',
'C' : 'categorical',
'D' : 'categorical',
'E' : 'categorical',
'F' : 'categorical',
'G' : 'categorical',
'H' : 'categorical',
'I' : 'categorical'
}
profile = ProfileReport(df_data, type_schema=type_schema)

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? If not, you should include is as an edit to the original post or leave it as a comment for clarity.